# Find name and add sentence

Tags: c#

I have a name List (name.txt) and want if find "David" name , A line before add "find my name"

For example:

Name.txt:

> Jacob 
>  William 
>  Ethan 
>  James 
>   **David**

I want =

> Jacob 
>  William 
>  Ethan 
>  James 
>   **"find my word"** 
>   **David**

Tip: David name may have been repeated many times.

I want Repeat "find my word".

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists("name.txt"))
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText("name.txt");
        string sensentence = "find my name"; 
        //I don't know how to proceed
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
string line = string.Empty;
//lines used to store the lines read from the file
List<string> lines = new List<string>();
//path used to store the path of the file 
string path = @"c:\Name.txt";
//check whether file exists or not
if (File.Exists(path)) {
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
    //read the line from file
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        //check whether line is equal to the searched word
        if (line == "David") { // Give your search term here!
            lines.Add("\"find my word\"");
        }
        //add the line to lines string list
        lines.Add(line);
    }
    //close the file
    file.Close();
}  
//write all the lines stored in lines to the file
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the lines into a list and find all the indices of `"David"`. Iterate all indices in the reverse order and insert the new text in the identified indices.

Finally you can write the file back.

Try code like followong. It will work.

```
        var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\name.txt").ToList();
        IEnumerable<int> allIndices = allLines.Select((s, i) => new { Str = s, Index = i })
                    .Where(x => x.Str == "David")
                    .Select(x => x.Index);

        foreach (int matchingIndex in allIndices.Reverse())
        {
            allLines.Insert(matchingIndex, "find my name");
        }          
        File.WriteAllLines(@"d:\name.txt", allLines.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

First you could use `File.ReadAllLines` and store the names in a list, then  you could use `Enumerable.Range` combined with `Where` to find the `indexes` of `"David"` inside that list. Then you use the `indexes` and the `Insert` method to insert `"find my name"` inside the list before the name `"David"`.

```
if (File.Exists(@"D:\name.txt"))
{
    List<string> nameList = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\name.txt").ToList();
    int[] indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, nameList.Count).Where(i => nameList[i] == "David").ToArray();
    int shift = 0;
    foreach (var index in indexes)
    {
        nameList.Insert(index + shift, "find my name");
        shift++;
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\name.txt", nameList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[File.ReadAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2), [File.WriteAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2) can open a file and read or write to it, and also close the file after each operation.

The array of strings returned by `File.ReadAllLines()` can then be used as a source to perform the required changes to its elements and then written again using `File.WriteAllLines()`:

```
string Sentence = "Find my name";
string MyName = "David";

if (File.Exists("[SomeFilePath]")) {
    string[] AllNames = File
                .ReadAllLines("[SomeFilePath]")
                .Select(name => { return (name == MyName) 
                                ? Sentence + Environment.NewLine + name : name;
              }).ToArray();

    if (AllNames.Count() > 0)
        File.WriteAllLines("[SomeFilePath]", AllNames);
}
```